# How to bypass a public API's usage limit block?

Tags: api, node.js

I'm trying to build a database with information that I can get with a lot of http GET requests to the target server's API. The problem is that they obviously do have restrictions.

After 80+ requests, I get an error message if I try to fetch any more data. At first, I thought it was just an IP block, so I tried using a VPN to change my IP but the server's API is still returning an error message, so they gotta have another way of blocking users from the API.

Which methods are out there to block users from fetching data from a public API besides IP block?

I'm using NodeJS by the way, no browser involved, just http GET requests from a node file.

Comment: Have you checked the API's terms of usage?  If you're hitting a rate-limit block, you're probably in violation of them.

Comment: Do you send any identifying information along with the GET request? What kind of error message are you receiving?

Comment: I fail to see why people are voting this as off-topic. If you'd read the question body and not just the title, you'd see that OP is asking _what methods exist_ other than IP blocks to limit accesses from an individual.

Comment: @forest: If the OP just wants to know what method exist to limit access then why is he asking for bypassing these limits in the title? And, as one can see from the body of the text the OP is actually trying to bypass the limits by using a VPN and now asks for more information how the limit might be enforced since just using a VPN did not work. The question would be quite different if the OP would for example ask how such limits can be implemented in order to protect his own server.

Comment: @forest I have to agree with Steffan. Either the API documentation will help or the ToS will help, or contacting the API support will help. But, "what are all the ways they could be limiting me?" is not a great question.